# Web API with Mulitple Get methods

Tags: methods, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api service and have 3 Get methods on the conroller.

- `public IQueryable<OrgResults> Get()`
- `public IQueryable<OrgResults>Get(string Name)`
- `public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)`

I've seen aswers that recommend using the `[Route()]` attribute on the Get method and call that instead.

But i've also seen examples where the routing template is overriden to handle an action request.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}",
                    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });

routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");
```

Can the second solution work in my case where I have a Get method that can take an Int parameter and one that can take a string paramater, and how would i define that ?

Or is the first option using the attributes the correct way to do this ?

Comment: Attribute routing is newer. I like it for the simple fact that the rule is right above the action is it supposed to match.